# Banshee suddenly stopped playing music - how do I get it working again?

Tags: 11.04, sound, banshee, mp3, gstreamer

Suddenly I can't play music in Banshee 2.0. Just suddenly stopped working today.

I reinstalled Banshee and Gstreamer, but that hasn't helped.

Searching on Google, the ***[Error 14:13:13.192] GStreamer core error: StateChange***  error has come up a lot, and a lot of people reported it as a bug, but I found no corrections or fixes that I could apply.

What do I do to get Banshee to play again?

Here is a section of the stream of errors I got when I ran Banshee from the command line:

```
[Info  14:12:49.083] [Streamrecorder.Gst.Marshaller] gstreamer version found: GStreamer 0.10.32
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
bpm_detect got error: Could not open file "song.mp3" for reading. gstfilesrc.c(1039): gst_file_src_start (): /GstPipeline:pipeline/GstFileSrc:filesrc:
system error: Permission denied
[Warn  14:12:51.417] Asked to invalidate 0+0,0x0 for Hyena.Data.Gui.ColumnCellRating but no CanvasManager!
[Error 14:13:13.192] GStreamer core error: StateChange
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
[Error 14:13:14.545] GStreamer core error: StateChange
[Warn  14:13:14.567] Service disposal (MprisService) threw an exception - System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
```

Comment: Are you able to play music in Totem (Movie Player) or Rhythmbox?  Can you play files other than mp3s?  If you have an ogg or flac file to test, that would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the tip on testing with other media players. Sometimes you need a reminder to do the obvious troubleshooting steps.

VLC also didn't work but gave me a slightly more informative error, saying that the audio device was not present.

A little Googling led to this command:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

... which solved the problem.

Comment: Brilliant that solved my problem completely thanks!